# node,js add an outer level to json using a variable as key name

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a standard `JSON` stored in a variable and am able to add a top level key when directly using text but a variable,

```
[{"myKey":"my value"}]
```

is stored in `orginalJson`. I then add a top level key as text

```
var newJson = JSON.parse(orginalJson);
newJson = { myText: newJson };
```

gives

```
{ "myText": [{"myKey":"my value"}]}
```

I would now like to replace the text in the code with a variable

```
var newVar = "newtext";    
var newJson = JSON.parse(orginalJson);
newJson = { newVar: newJson };
```

however I do not get the var value as expected, just the name of var not the value

expecting

```
{ "newtext": [{"myKey":"my value"}]}
```

but get

```
{ "newVar ": [{"myKey":"my value"}]}
```

what is the correct way to use a var in this instance. I have read other posts suggesting using a `push` but I have not had any luck understanding the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of using var is;

```
var newVar = "newText"
var newJson = {}
newJson[newVar] = JSON.parse(originalJson)
```

This will give you

```
{ "newVar ": [{"myKey":"my value"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to **first** create the object, *then* use bracket notation for the key
Because you're using the same variable to hold the newly modified value, we'll need a temporary object.
The better option would probably be to not use the same variabel twice

```js
var orginalJson = '{"test":"test"}';

var newVar = "newtext";
var newJson = JSON.parse(orginalJson);
var tempObj = {};

tempObj[newVar] = newJson;

newJson = tempObj;

console.log(newJson)
```

Or in ES2015 you can use dynamic keys

```js
var orginalJson = '{"test":"test"}';

var newVar = "newtext";
var newJson = JSON.parse(orginalJson);

newJson = { [newVar]: newJson };

console.log(newJson);
```

Comment: thanks for the code. This answer does work and explains the process. thanks